# Update a postgresql table with the results of query

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table with 2 columns:

1. code
2. pharm

The code column doesn not contain unique values. There are duplicates in it. What I want is to count these values as:

```
SELECT code, COUNT(code) FROM TABLE GROUP BY code ORDER BY 1
```

And use the COUNT result from the query to assign it in the PHARM column. So the final table should look like this:

```
CODE  PHARM
AB     3
AB     3
AB     3
CD     2
CD     2
```

...

I tried to experiment with the `UPDATE` query as:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET (pharm) = (SELECT COUNT(code) FROM TABLE GROUP BY code)
```

However this doesnt work and I am quite sure is not the right way to do it. I guess I need to build some function to do this type of update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a join of the table to your query:

```
update tablename t
set pharm = g.counter
from (
  select code, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by code
) g
where g.code = t.code;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Mu2fEVLyvirWodkhW1LyN/1).
or:

```
update tablename t
set pharm = (select count(*) from tablename where code = t.code);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Mu2fEVLyvirWodkhW1LyN/0).
or:

```
update tablename t
set pharm = (select count(*) filter (where code = t.code) from tablename);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Mu2fEVLyvirWodkhW1LyN/2).

Comment: Thanks. I realized this after I post the question. I did though the slow way. I have created a temp table with the COUNT and ID and then I join the initial table with the temp one. Your way is much better.